# Asp.Net Authorization rule precedence

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I am studying for a Microsoft exam and am going through some sample questions.  I have this question:

"You are developing an ASP.NET Web Application which is configured to use the membership and role providers.

You need to allow all users to perform a HTTP GET but must allow only the user named Moderator to perform a POST operation.  Which configuration should you add to the web.config file?"

```
<authorization>
  <deny verbs="POST" users="*" />
  <allow verbs="POST" users="Moderator" />
  <allow verbs="GET" users="*" />
</authorization>

<authorization>
  <allow verbs="GET" users="*" />
  <allow verbs="POST" users="Moderator" />
  <deny verbs="POST" users="*" />
</authorization>
```

There were two other answers but they were obviously wrong so I haven't replicated them here.

The only difference I can spot between the two sets of rules is the order in which the rules are placed.

The correct answer is the second set of rules.  Here the rule first Allows POST access for "Moderator" and then removes it for everyone else.  This seems counter-intuitive to me - to give 1 person a privilege, then remove that privilege from everyone and yet the 1 person still has the privilege afterwards.

If anything the first set of rules makes more sense - first deny everyone then selectively give access to individuals.  Apparently this is wrong though!

Can anyone explain why this is the case so I can understand this better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a case of first come first served. ASP.NET processes the rules in order until it hits one that matches, therefore in the first scenario it will hit the `deny` rule for `POST` *before* it reaches the `allow`.

> If anything the first set of rules makes more sense - first deny everyone then selectively give access to individuals.

That's not quite how it works. The rules are checked *per request*, therefore, what the first rules are basically saying is:

1. Deny all `POST` requests from everyone.
2. Allow `POST` requests for Moderator.
3. Allow `GET` requests for everyone.

All in that order. The problem here is when Moderator sends in a `POST` request, it will match the first rule (as it's for *everyone*) and be denied. However, the second scenario is saying:

1. Allow `GET` requests for everyone.
2. Allow `POST` requests for Moderator.
3. Deny `POST` requests for everyone.

So when Moderator sends a `Post` request, it will match the 2nd rule and allow the request to continue. If anyone else sends in a `POST` request, they will hit the 3rd rule and be denied.

Comment: I understand now thankyou.  It is simply a case of first come first served.  Asp.Net finds "Allow Moderator" first and because it matches, it can ignore the rest.

Comment: Boom. This is exactly what I needed. +1.

Answer (score 1):

The rules are evaluated in order, and the first rule that matches the current "set of attributes" (=request type, user is authenticated or not, user roles etc) is used. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Given a set of merged rules for an application, ASP.NET starts at the
>   head of the list and checks rules until the first match is found. The
>   default configuration for ASP.NET contains an 
>   element, which authorizes all users. (By default, this rule is applied
>   last.) If no other authorization rules match, the request is allowed.
>   If a match is found and the match is a deny element, the request is
>   returned with the 401 HTTP status code. If an allow element matches,
>   the module allows the request to be processed further.